# Html2Canvas: Different image produced by different devices

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am using Html2Canvas to convert the contents of a div to an base64 string.

But, I am struggling to configure it correctly. It is producing different results for different results. My guess is that it's something to do with screen resolution.

Here is my code:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#dpo_base_image'),
{
    height: $('#dpo_base_image').height(),
    width: $('#dpo_base_image').width(),
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
}
).then(canvas => {
   $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'properties[_DataUrl]').attr('value', canvas.toDataURL()).appendTo('form');
});
```

Looking at the documentation I have a number of options as below:

1. Scale: The scale to use for rendering. Defaults to the browsers device pixel ratio.
2. width: The width of the canvas.
3. height: The height of the canvas.
4. windowWidth: Window width to use when rendering Element, which may affect things like Media queries.
5. windowHeight: Window height to use when rendering Element, which may affect things like Media queries.

There are more detailed here: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

I am a back-end developer and don't have the knowledge of things like how screen sizes or resolutions could be affecting this.

Can anyone point me in the direction of consistently getting an image of 2000px wide and 2479px high?

I have tried putting those values in the width/height parameters but I still get different image results.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can try set scale  option to 1

Comment: did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @el-aasi unfortunately not. i ended up grabbing the div contents and combining it with the CSS and creating the image on the back-end

Comment: good to know :)